# Copying Azure storage blobs - efficiency

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

Here is the code that I wrote to copy blobs from one Azure storage account to another, and it's about an order of magnitude slower than azcopy. Any ideas why so much difference?

```
        const int maxCount = 0x1000;
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = maxCount;
        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(maxCount, maxCount);

        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        var maxTasks = 0x100;

        foreach (var blob in blobs)
        {
            var blobClient = sourceContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);
            var sourceUri = blobClient.Uri;

            var targetBlobPath = $"{targetInnerPath}/{blob.Name}";
            var targetBlobClient = targetContainerClient.GetBlobClient(targetBlobPath);

            var operation = targetBlobClient.StartCopyFromUri(new Uri($"{sourceUri}{sourceSas}"));
            var task = operation.WaitForCompletionAsync().AsTask();
            tasks.Add(task);

            if (tasks.Count < maxTasks)
                continue;

            Task.WaitAny(tasks.ToArray());
            tasks.RemoveAll(cur => cur.IsCompleted);
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: Try by reducing the number of concurrent tasks. Ideally they should be the same as the number of virtual cores on the machine where the code is running.

Comment: @GauravMantri this doesn't make much difference.

Comment: I noticed that you are calling `WaitForCompletionAsync()` which can also cause slowness. Do you really need to ensure that the copy operation completes successfully?

Comment: @GauravMantri yes I do.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of things that can be improved in this code:

1. **Throttling and Rate Limiting**: Depending on the type of storage account and the number of concurrent operations, you might be hitting some throttling limits. azcopy might handle these in a more graceful way, respecting the service's limits and retrying more efficiently.
2. **Content Size**: Depending on the size of your blobs, different approaches might be needed. If your blobs are small, the overhead of setting up and tearing down connections might dominate the time taken. If your blobs are large, efficient chunking and parallelism will be key.
3. **Error Handling and Retries**: The code snippet does not show how errors are handled. Efficient handling of errors and retries could make a difference in performance.
4. **Client-Side CPU Overhead**: Managing many tasks can create substantial CPU overhead. You may want to look into managing your threads more effectively or changing your logic to use something like a producer/consumer pattern.
5. **Memory Consumption**: Managing a large number of tasks can also lead to large memory consumption, depending on the size and nature of the blobs

Here's an updated version that fixes some of these issues

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

//...

const int maxConcurrency = 100; // Set this to a value suitable for your application
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrency);
var tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var blob in blobs)
{
    await semaphore.WaitAsync(); // Wait for a free slot

    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        try
        {
            var blobClient = sourceContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);
            var sourceUri = blobClient.Uri;

            var targetBlobPath = $"{targetInnerPath}/{blob.Name}";
            var targetBlobClient = targetContainerClient.GetBlobClient(targetBlobPath);

            var operation = targetBlobClient.StartCopyFromUri(new Uri($"{sourceUri}{sourceSas}"));
            await operation.WaitForCompletionAsync();

            // Handle successful operation if needed
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle error - you may want to log the exception or retry the operation
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release(); // Release the slot
        }
    }));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // Wait for all tasks to complete
```

Another option you could try is using streaming, it might make things faster when running concurrent tasks:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized;

//...

const int maxConcurrency = 100; // Set this to a value suitable for your application
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrency);
var tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var blob in blobs)
{
    await semaphore.WaitAsync(); // Wait for a free slot

    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            var blobClient = sourceContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);

            // Read from the source blob
            Stream readStream = (await blobClient.OpenReadAsync()).Value.Content;

            var targetBlobPath = $"{targetInnerPath}/{blob.Name}";
            var targetBlobClient = targetContainerClient.GetBlobClient(targetBlobPath);

            // Write to the target blob
            var blockBlobClient = targetBlobClient as BlockBlobClient;
            await blockBlobClient.UploadAsync(readStream);

            readStream.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle error - you may want to log the exception or retry the operation
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release(); // Release the slot
        }
    }));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // Wait for all tasks to complete
```

So, what I've done here is pretty simple. I read from each source blob and then write to the matching target blob, using streams to do the heavy lifting. I'm using something called `SemaphoreSlim` to make sure I don't go overboard with too many things happening at once. And yeah, I've thrown in some basic error handling too.

Oh, a quick heads-up: I'm assuming that the target container is using block blobs. If that's not the case, you'll need to tweak the code a bit.

And as always, don't just throw this into production without testing it first! Feel free to play around with it, and see if you need to make any other tweaks to suit your specific needs.

Comment: Did you check if your code is actually faster? Because the second sample is guaranteed to be much slower due to downloading/uploading data rather than transferring it directly from storage to storage.